# Issue on delete record from SQL Server database through C# program

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, linq

I'm new to C# programming. I've written a program in C# which has been connected to a SQL Server database through LINQ connector. Everything ran smoothly. But now I get below error when I want to delete a record from program with a specific condition:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

This is my C# code:

```
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Sales system ", "Are you sure to delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        string photo = txtPhoto.ToString();

        var edit = db.tblPersons.Where(c => c.PhotoNo == photo || c.ReceiptNo == photo).FirstOrDefault();
        db.tblPersons.Remove(edit);
        db.SaveChanges();

        MessageBox.Show("Info deleted");
    }
}
```

Does anyone know about my issue in this occasion?

Comment: I suspect that you need to check how the `txtPhoto` field is getting populated. It looks like maybe `photo` is an invalid value, which is causing `edit` to be null, and entity framework cannot remove a `null` value from `tblPersons`.

Comment: `edit` is null, obviously. Find out why + check for null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that control is a textbox, however, get the text.

example:

```
string photo = txtPhoto.Text;
```

Comment: The `.ToString()` is not neccessary.  Should be just `var photo = txtPhoto.Text;`

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your `var edit` is not null before try to remove

```cs
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Sales system ", "Are you sure to delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string photo = txtPhoto.ToString();

            var edit = db.tblPersons.Where(c => c.PhotoNo == photo || c.ReceiptNo == photo).FirstOrDefault();
            if(edit != null)
            {
              db.tblPersons.Remove(edit);
              db.SaveChanges();
              MessageBox.Show("Info deleted");
            }
            else
            {
             MessageBox.Show(photo + " Incorrect");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will stop the error from throwing, but it will not solve the issue of why the variable `txtPhoto` has an invalid value which is likely the root cause of the issue.